# How to configure JS/TS debugger on PhpStorm like on VSCode with attach option?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, phpstorm, vscode-debugger

I am moving from VSCode to PhpStorm. In VSCode I could configure debugger with attach mode.
What is attach mode? It allows you to debug your app in existing browser window. In launch mode new instance of browser is started.
In PhpStorm I can't see that option in docs. Do I search in wrong way? Or there is a trick to do that?

Thank you for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Attach to Node.js/Chrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) run configuration to attach the debugger to a running Node.js process/Chrome browser started with `--remote-debugging-port` option. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.3/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#node_debugging_running_application for more info.

Comment: Thank you for response. So I didn't read docs properly.

Comment: Hmm.. I have chrome started with --debug=9229 flag (from docs) and with --remote-debugging-port=9229 (from your suggestion) and I have info "Host xyz:8000 is unresolved" when I run debug configuration. I have xyx:8000 opened on chrome and it doesn't see it. What is maybe important that address is exposed by docker container, but I can open it on windows environment in browser. Maybe phpStorm doesn't see it?

Comment: did you specify the host name in the run configuration? such connections are blocked, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34537/Cannot-attach-to-remote-nodejs-after-upgrade-to-2018.2#focus=Comments-27-3096382.0-0. Try using the IP instead

Comment: It is good idea with IP, but I think this is not the case. In VSCode I could debug by only running Chrome with flag, which you mentioned in main answer. Now I think I should run node process with inspect flag - without it there are no changes to work, am I wrong? I would prefer do it in VSCode way instead of running node with additional flag, but if it is necessary, I will have to do that.

Comment: if you need attaching a debugger to a running Node.js process, then yes, you need starting this process with `--inspect` flag. If you start Node from within the IDE, you don't need passing flags explicitly, just create a Node.js run configuration and press **Debug**

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Now is all clear. So in VSCode it is more friendly - it is good to know.

Comment: don't agree - in VSCode, you also need starting Node with `--inspect` to be able to attach to the running Node process using the `attach` config

Comment: ws://127.0.0.1:9229 - previously inspect was not set. Now 9229 is present.
Live reload server is on localhost:5000 - maybe this is important?
UI config:
127.0.0.1:8000 - host setting;
9229 - port;
Chrome or node.js > 6.3 checked;
reconnect automatically checked;
Still the same - unresolved host.
What can I change yet?

Comment: When I go to chrome://inspect/#devices my card xyz:8000 is present - previously wasn't.